# Simple Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a lot of:

```
FooModel f = new FooModel();
..
Bar Model b = new BarModel();
```

I need to retreive any Model Object from a Java source code but I don't want to complete declaration. I just want the Object Declaration.

I tried with a regex (where strLine is a String line in a InputStreamReader):

```
String pattern = ".*Model (.+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);

if(m.find())
    System.out.print(m.group(1) + "\n");
```

I am able to get the instanciation. But I would do the samething, but for Object declaration (before the "=").

How can I do this?

I can do it

```
m.group(0).replace(m.group(1),"");
```

but it's not a real regex.

Comment: This will never work reliably. You'll need to use a proper Java parser if you want completely correct results. What about the following code, with a comment: `FooModel f = new FooModel(); /* make a new FooModel() */`?

Comment: Yes, I know It will not work, but how can this could be done?

Comment: m.group(0) instead of m.group(1)

Comment: Actually group(0) would show the complete FooModel f = new FooModel();

Comment: Why not just use Eclipse and search for all `com.example.*Model` types?

Comment: Because I need to do it using java classes..

Comment: How about String pattern = "(.*Model[^=]*)="; System.out.print(m.group(1) + "\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one initiation statement in one line:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class  FindModel
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "  FooModel f = new FooModel();";
        String pattern = "([^\\s]*?Model[^=]*)=";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        if(m.find())
            System.out.print(m.group(1) + "\n");
     }
}
```

If you have more than one statements in one line:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class  FindModel
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "  FooModel f = new FooModel();int i=0,j; BarModel b = new BarModel();";
        String pattern = "([^;\\s]*?Model[^=]*)=.*?;";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while(m.find())
            System.out.print(m.group(1) + "\n");
     }
}
```

Output:

```
FooModel f
BarModel b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\w+ \\w+)\\s*=.*new.*Model.*
```